# "System.*" Files in Visual Basic?

Tags: vb.net

How are those files constallated and where can I find more information about them?

It is recent version of Visual Studio I'm using.

Comment: It was meant in the sense of "how it is put together", to learn more about it. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The different system assemblies live in the [Global Assembly Cache](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Global_Assembly_Cache) (GAC).

You do not normally need direct access to these files - see [How to: Add or Remove References By Using the Add Reference Dialog Box](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wkze6zky.aspx) on MSDN.

The assemblies that are in the GAC will appear on the .NET tab of the dialog.

To use a namespace directly in the class (so you do not need to fully qualify it), use the [`Imports` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7f38zh8x.aspx).